# Facebook shows conversation as unread even though last message was posted by me

Tags: facebook

Often when I reply to a Facebook message, the message stays marked as "unread".

For instance in the screenshot below (messenger.com) the first and third conversations are OK, but the conversation in the middle is problematic: Even though the last message is by me, the person name stays bold, which I believed was supposed to indicate unread messages:

[image: You bold]

The bold/not bold status is consistent across messenger.com/fb.com/Android app.
It has been happening for years, and it is very annoying as it makes actual unread messages harder to notice.

**QUESTION**: Is it expected behavior, and I am misunderstanding the UI?
If this is a Facebook bug, are there known workarounds?

Comment: I can't see any reason it would be you misunderstanding the UI. It doesn't make any sense from design perspective. It also happens to me a lot, pretty annoying.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of bugs in Facebook. As long as you’ve read them. I assume you tried refreshing page, closing/opening again and turning off the device. I’d say when the next update is done it might rectify this.

Comment: 3 years after I posted my question, it is still happening, so I guess some workaround (if possible something faster than turning off my computer) would be useful.

Comment: It's 2021 and the issue is still there. lol